# Spatial autocorrelation correction with glmmTMB

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, spatial, glmmtmb, spatial-correlation

I am currently working on a dataset (count data) in which one observation corresponds to one day of monitoring at a site.
The overall protocol is to monitor groups of sites along transects. Almost all transects (and by extension almost all sites) were monitored several times. Sometimes, several transects were monitored at on given date.

I would like to be able to predict the abundance of the studied species according to multiple landscape and meteorological metrics. To do so, I tried to construct GLMMs (with a negative binomial distribution) using the glmmTMB function:

```
Abundance ~ environmental variables + meteorological variables + Julian day (and its quadratic effect) + year (in factor) + (1 | transect / site) + (1 | date)
```

However, my models suffer from spatial autocorrelation. I tested it with the testSpatialAutocorrelation function from the DHARMa package:

```
groupLocations = aggregate(countData[, which(colnames(countData) %in% c("x","y"))]
                           , list(countData$xy), mean)
groupLocations$xy <- unique(countData$xy)
res <- simulateResiduals(myModel)
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, countData$xy)
all(unique(res2$group) == groupLocations$xy)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2,x=groupLocations$x,y=groupLocations$y)
```

I would thus like to correct it, ideally using a covariance structure like those presented in this vignette : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html
So I tried to add `exp(pos + 0 | group)` to my model with (1) `countData$pos <- numFactor(countData$x, countData$y)`, (2) with group being a dummy variable, my sites IDs or my date IDs...
Whatever the solution I choose, it doesn't seem to work (R is working indefinitely).

I guess my problem might come from two main issues:

- the factI don't fully understand what the "group" metric sould be,
- the fact that I have several observations at the same location (but at different dates),

For information, latitude (y) and longitude (x) are in Lambert 93 in my dataset but I can transfrom them in WGS84 if needed.

****EDIT***
Here is an example of the type of data I use (but not the real ones, which are very heavy) and my code.
Interestingly with this small dataset, `exp(pos + 0 |group)` seems to work whether I define `group` as a dummy variable or as my site IDs, but with different results. In both cases, the testSpatialAutocorrelation function still detect spatial autocorrelation.

```
library(DHARMa)
library(glmmTMB)

rm(list=ls())

####I. Data creation####

newData <- data.frame(transect=c(rep("Transect_A",8*8),rep("Transect_B",10*3),rep("Transect_C",12)))
newData$site <- c(rep(paste0("Site_A",c(1:8)),8),rep(paste0("Site_B",c(1:10)),3),paste0("Site_C",c(1:12)))
newData$date <- c(rep("2001-05-03",8),rep("2001-06-25",8),rep("2002-06-04",8),rep("2002-07-15",8)
  ,rep("2003-04-28",8),rep("2003-05-16",8),rep("2003-06-30",8),rep("2003-07-24",8)
  ,rep("2001-06-02",10),rep("2002-07-15",10),rep("2003-05-08",10)
  ,rep("2033-05-08",12))

coordX_TA <- c(524623.6,524379.1,524379.1,524614.5,524877.1,525040.1,525185.0,525112.5)
coordX_TB <- c(527023.3,526769.7,526615.8,526652.0,526941.8,527258.7,527430.8,527566.6,527620.9,527783.9) 
coordX_TC <- c(525329.9,525148.8,525230.3,525447.6,525710.2,525945.7,526126.8,526172.0,526090.5,525927.5,525728.3,525683.0)

coordY_TA <- c(6705186,6705041,6704842,6704715,6704806,6704942,6705132,6705358)
coordY_TB <- c(6703728,6703593,6703357,6703094,6702941,6703022,6703194,6703420,6703665,6703864)
coordY_TC <- c(6700966,6700767,6700486,6700369,6700323,6700360,6700559,6700803,6701057,6701220,6701365,6701102)

newData$X <- c(rep(coordX_TA,8),rep(coordX_TB,3),coordX_TC)
newData$Y <- c(rep(coordY_TA,8),rep(coordY_TB,3),coordY_TC)

newData$abundance <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                       ,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,2,4,0,1,12,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
                       ,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,9,3,6,11,4,9,12)

newData$explanatoryVar <- c(rep(c(0.42899904,0.77110546,0.45891875,2.35145233,0.52373614,0.03604363,-0.20136060,3.23943293),8)
                          ,rep(c(0.21227248,1.31673835,3.63072002,1.29581033,3.55550595,1.36627219
                                 ,1.56734995,-0.11314501,-0.38866418,-0.18451185),3)
                          ,c(-0.39731842,-0.47077649,-0.46944891,-0.18973198,-0.53603923,-0.38094487,0.16941656,0.60947665
                             ,0.08765610,0.33079765,0.09083049,2.18221584))

####II. Model without correction####

newData$explanatoryVar_scaled <- scale(newData$explanatoryVar)

myModel <- glmmTMB(abundance ~ explanatoryVar + (1|transect/site) + (1|date)
                   , data = newData, family = "nbinom2",na.action="na.fail")

summary(myModel)

#test Spatial autocorrelation 

groupLocations = aggregate(newData[, which(colnames(newData) %in% c("X","Y"))]
                           , list(newData$site), mean)
groupLocations$site <- unique(newData$site)
res <- simulateResiduals(myModel)
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, newData$site)
all(unique(res2$group) == groupLocations$site)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2,x=groupLocations$X,y=groupLocations$Y)

####III. Model with correction####

newData$pos <- numFactor(scale(newData$X), scale(newData$Y))
# newData$group <- factor(rep(1, nrow(newData))) #group as a dummy variable
newData$group <- factor(newData$site)

myModelCorrection <- glmmTMB(abundance ~ explanatoryVar + (1|transect/site) + (1|date) + exp(pos + 0 | group)
                   ,data = newData, family = "nbinom2",na.action="na.fail")

summary(myModelCorrection)

#test Spatial autocorrelation 

groupLocations = aggregate(newData[, which(colnames(newData) %in% c("X","Y"))]
                           , list(newData$site), mean)
groupLocations$site <- unique(newData$site)
res <- simulateResiduals(myModelCorrection)
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, newData$site)
all(unique(res2$group) == groupLocations$site)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2,x=groupLocations$X,y=groupLocations$Y)
```

Comment: Have you seen if you can reproduce the volcano example "A spatial covariance example" in the [covstruct link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html), to understand the required structures?

Comment: Yes, I tried to reproduce this example by adding the same structure : exp(pos + 0 | group). Interestingly, for R not to run indefinitely, I have to define "group" as a dummy variable equal to 1 for instance (even if I have several observations by sites) and for my model to converge I have to define "pos" as my x and y scaled (i.e. longitude and latitude scaled beforehand). 
However, if I use the testSpatialAutocorrelation function on the residuals (using my x and y not scaled), it seems that this structure does not correct the autocorrelation issue, or even makes it worse...

Comment: What if you group by both day and site?

Comment: Can you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ClaireRichards I'm not sure how I shoud do that ? By putting extra arguments in exp ?

Comment: @AlexJ , I tried to make a reproducible example (I'm relatively new on this plateform so feel free to tell me if it wasn't done right). I added it at the end of my question.

Comment: Because transect sampling tends to detect species with different probabilities depending on their distance from the transect, special techniques are usually needed to analyze the results.   This might be of more importance for the accuracy of your results than any other consideration. Some good explanations and advice are in Steven Thompson's book *Sampling.*

Comment: I think you properly took into consideration the clustering by date in your residual arguments.

Comment: I don't have any particular thoughts, although I agree with @whuber and also recommend Buckland's _Introduction to Distance Sampling_. For this particular data set in the reprex, I'm not sure you've got enough data to fit a spatial correlation structure + nested intercepts to a nbinom. I realise you've got a much larger set, but try to simplify until you get something working, and then go from there.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments.
@whuber You're right, I'll have to think about this particular sampling design and I will take a close look at this book, but I'm not sure that I will have to use special techniques as I work in relative abundance (what I care bout most is whether there are more individuals at one site than at another) and I use acoustic data (I know the distance threshold above which I no longer detect individuals).

Comment: @AlexJ I will also take a close look at this reference, thank you very much! Fortunately, my real dataset is made up of many more observations and replications, but you're right, my reprex is too small for such a structure and I'll will to check that my real dataset is big enough for it / whether I can simplify my model !

Comment: Having a distance threshold is a great thing to have!  Thompson describes how to exploit that.

Answer (score 2):

@Lea_M, I took a look at it, and I'm still learning about how to use these functions myself.
The [help info](https://rdrr.io/cran/DHARMa/man/testSpatialAutocorrelation.html) says you can have residual spatial autocorrelation even if the model takes care of it. I added the command rotation="estimated" during the recalculation and the autocorrelation is no longer statistically significant.

```
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, newData$site, rotation="estimated") 
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2,x=groupLocations$X,y=groupLocations$Y)

data:  res2
observed = 0.072138, expected = -0.034483, sd = 0.056906, p-value = 0.06098
alternative hypothesis: Distance-based autocorrelation

[Quantile command help][2]
```

That said, the residual plot doesn't look great [image: pretty bad.] and I'm not certain why.

Another (non-exclusive) method suggested is to condition the simulations on the random effects, but it states [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/glmmTMB/man/simulate.glmmTMB.html) that for glmmTMB, it's not yet possible to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I should have taken a closer look at the testSpatialAutocorrelation function help! With the command rotation="estimated", it does indeed appear that the spatial autocorrelation is corrected! The only problem that remains, however, is that when I use my real dataset, I cannot define "group" as my site IDs (R runs indefinitely or more exactly several hours at least, which is problematic because I need to perform a dredge). Finally, indeed, the residual graphs are not great for my example, fortunately they are OK for my real dataset!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. It does seem like you should be able to account for the fact that the sites are clustered within the transects for the spatial correlation. I was able to write exp(pos + 0 | transect/site) but for this data, the results were the same, though it gave me a longer correlation structure. I'm stabbing in the dark here, I guess, but it seems to me like the random slopes of the spatial correlation should be nested, too.

Comment: Your're right... I'll test this on my dataset !